# Query OR Statement

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

Can anyone help me with a query please? I am not sure how to add this OR statement

```
select id, status, from custom_Object__c where id in ('id1' or 'id2')
```

I have also tried

```
select id, status, from custom_Object__c where (id = 'id1' or 'id2')
```

Can anyone tell me how to use an OR statement for 2 ids within IN statement? Thanks!

I have also tried

```
select id, status, from custom_Object__c where (id = 'id1' or 'id2')
```

Can anyone tell me how to use an OR statement for 2 ids within IN statement?

Comment: MySQL is not the same thing as SQL Server nor Salesforce, please tag the actual RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: Isn't it just `id in ('id1', 'id2')` - OR is the same thing as IN

Comment: select id, status, from custom_Object__c where id in ('id1', 'id2')  works for sql-server

Comment: As the above for IN if you do OR you have to do where (id = 'id1' OR id = 'id2')  Though IN is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To employ an OR condition in a where clause you can do this:

```
select id, status 
from custom_Object__c 
where (id = id1' OR id ='id2')
```

The `IN` construct in SQL can be used as a "shortcut", for example the equivalent of the above query is as follows:

```
select id, status 
from custom_Object__c 
where id in ('id1','id2')
```

Here the you simply list out the values that id may equal separated by a comma (& you do not need to specify "or" in that list).